# Best practices and tools for improving web server's performance in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, webserver, performance, asp.net-4.0

Before the question here is what  we tried to test the performance website. We simulated 80 users simultaneously on the website using [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/). So, I am working on database issues and other problem. But one of the problems was the web server performance was not good and it was maxing out.

So , I am in the process of improving the web server's performance and have downloaded [Redgate Performance profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/) and also [dottrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/). I was going to get into using these but I before that I thought of asking all you guyz who have done this before since I am newbie in this area what steps should I take additionally. Any advice or steps to be taken or any other tools you can suggest will be of great help. Basically I am just trying to know the best practices and tools to be used when profiling an asp.net mvc application.

Comment: You already have the best tools.

Answer (score 1):

There can be a million reasons why you're experiencing slow performance. Maybe it's just some method/page that takes long time to execute or consumes too much memory or did you mean that the overall performance is not good. Maybe you just need to upgrade your hardware, who knows. I would definitely try to locate the bottleneck by running a few counters in Windows Performance Monitor for CPU, RAM, Network, disk system on web server and db server while running JMeter. This should give you some ideas what could be wrong.