# Free Tools and ways for profiling ASP.NET MVC Web Server performance?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, webserver, performance

We ran Jmeter on our application and found that our web server was running relatively slow. I have asked this [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269955/best-practices-and-tools-for-improving-web-servers-performance-in-asp-net-mvc) but I was hoping to find some free tools can I use to profile it and identify bottlnecks ?

Also do I need to look at memory profiling on the server? What are the best steps I can take towards optimizing the web server performance ? Basically I am trying to optimize the web server to the fullest so just wanted to know all the steps can be taken to do it.

So,if anyone can list all the steps or optimizations than can be done on web server when using `asp.net mvc 2.0`, `IIS 7.0` and `SQL Server 2005`.Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978566 plus many others

Comment: @rboarman: Maybe this is a sign that there's general dissatisfaction with whats out there at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the MVC mini profiler.  Written by the StackOverFlow people

http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/

Answer (score 1):

These are great tools and have a 14 day free trial:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/buy/index.jsp - Definitely not free, but pretty intuitive and very helpful.